# Scale of the data after PCA

Tags: pca

I have 4 standard normal features on which I perform PCA. I then take the first principal component (with all of the components). Is it possible to a priori say what is the max and the min value that the transformed series will have?

I guess, if we assume that the original standard normal features never exceed +/- 5, then the max of the final transformed series would be the PCA coefficients product summed by 5? But is it possible that the PCA coefficients are [1, 1, 1, 1] in this case? Or is there some sort of a bound on what the PCA coefficients can be?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can determine the max and min of your transformed series if you normalize after your PCA step, as your title implies.

**Have you tried L2-norm after your PCA step?** This might get you what you are looking for by constraining the values between 0 and 1.

You can, of course, customize this to suit your needs.

Comment: what do you mean by L2-norm after my PCA?

Comment: It's has multiple names I suppose. It's basically a euclidean distance vector norm: 
  1. [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html)
  2. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm)

If you are interested, you could look at techniques like non-negative matrix factorization (NNMF), which constrains matrix elements to positive-only values.